# Tweenmax opacity remains 1 for a brief moment when page reloads

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I have implemented TweenMax from Gsap and made a landing page intro wherein the loading container, there are three divs containing three h5 elements positioned in the center using absolute. First I did StaggerFrom{ opacity 0 } to staggerTo{ opacity 1 }.
But for some reason as soon as I reload the page, I can see all the three h5 elements stacked on top of each other for a few milliseconds.

https://codepen.io/pranaymajee/pen/PomMaVM

On codepen it seems to work fine but on my browser its not.

```js
TweenMax.to(
  ".loadcon",
  2, {
    y: "-100%",
    ease: Expo.easeInOut,
    delay: 6,
  },
);


TweenMax.staggerFrom(
  ".loadtext",
  1, {
    x: "-80",
    ease: Power3.easeInOut,
    opacity: "0",
  },
  2
);
TweenMax.staggerTo(
  ".loadtext",
  0.8, {
    x: "80",
    ease: Power3.easeInOut,
    delay: 1.2,
    opacity: "0",
  },
  2
);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.loadcon{
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loadtext{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.loadtext h5{
  font-family: "Cyrene";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="loadcon">
        <div class="loadtext">
            <h5>Learn</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="loadtext">
            <h5>Code</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="loadtext">
            <h5>Repeat</h5>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

depen it seems to work fine but its happening on my browser
Any solutions ?

Comment: You're making of [the most common GSAP mistakes](https://greensock.com/mistakes/). I recommend that you fix them! Also there's no real reason to continue using the old versions of GSAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a timing problem, which is probably amerliorated in codepen because in that the code is run within an iframe.

The loadtexts need to start off at opacity 0 so they don't show as soon as they are loaded and then set to opacity 1 just before the tween max code is called.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.loadcon{
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loadtext{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  }
  .opacity1 {
  opacity: 1; /* ADDED */
}

.loadtext h5{
  font-family: "Cyrene";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="loadcon">
        <div class="loadtext">
            <h5>Learn</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="loadtext">
            <h5>Code</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="loadtext">
            <h5>Repeat</h5>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  const loadtexts = document.querySelectorAll('.loadtext');
  loadtexts.forEach(loadtext => {
    loadtext.classList.add('opacity1');
  });
  TweenMax.to(
  ".loadcon",
  2, {
    y: "-100%",
    ease: Expo.easeInOut,
    delay: 6,
  },
);


TweenMax.staggerFrom(
  ".loadtext",
  1, {
    x: "-80",
    ease: Power3.easeInOut,
    opacity: "0",
  },
  2
);
TweenMax.staggerTo(
  ".loadtext",
  0.8, {
    x: "80",
    ease: Power3.easeInOut,
    delay: 1.2,
    opacity: "0",
  },
  2
);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: runnning as an SO snippet also will have different timing considerations so this code needs to be run direct in a browser to give a proper test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.loadcon{
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loadtext{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  }
  .opacity1 {
  opacity: 1; /* ADDED */
}

.loadtext h5{
  font-family: "Cyrene";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="loadcon">
        <div class="loadtext">
            <h5>Learn</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="loadtext">
            <h5>Code</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="loadtext">
            <h5>Repeat</h5>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  const loadtexts = document.querySelectorAll('.loadtext');
  loadtexts.forEach(loadtext => {
    loadtext.classList.add('opacity1');
  });
  TweenMax.to(
  ".loadcon",
  2, {
    y: "-100%",
    ease: Expo.easeInOut,
    delay: 6,
  },
);


TweenMax.staggerFrom(
  ".loadtext",
  1, {
    x: "-80",
    ease: Power3.easeInOut,
    opacity: "0",
  },
  2
);
TweenMax.staggerTo(
  ".loadtext",
  0.8, {
    x: "80",
    ease: Power3.easeInOut,
    delay: 1.2,
    opacity: "0",
  },
  2
);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many Thanks ! Its working now. Yes I tried the old code on GitHub repository as well, there also it was not working. But now it is :)

Answer (score 0):

may a simpler approach than above set opacity:0

```
.loadtext{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%
  left: 50%;
  opacity:0;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Then change your `staggerTo()` and `staggerFrom()` functions

```
TweenMax.to(".loadcon",
  2, {
    y: "-100%",
    ease: Expo.easeInOut,
    delay: 6,
  },
);

TweenMax.staggerTo(
  ".loadtext",
  1, {
    x: "80",
    ease: Power3.easeInOut,
    opacity: "1",
  },
  2
);
TweenMax.staggerFrom(
  ".loadtext",
  0.8, {
    x: "-80",
    ease: Power3.easeInOut,
    delay: 1.2,
    opacity: "0",
  },
  2
);
```

You also have a lot of duplicate css between `.loadedText{}` and `.loadedtext h5{}` which is unnecessary.

[image]

https://codepen.io/non_tech_guy/pen/qBmeJOj

Comment: Actually this is a code snippet from my project that's why some line are not required here. I tried your solution before but didn't get the desired result.

Comment: it works for me, I have updated my answer to include the animation sample and a link to the codepen.

Comment: I don't have the stacking of h5 elements as you reported in your question in my codepen example.

Comment: the issue can be seen when you create a local HTML CSS JS file. Codepen is using an iframe for displaying the result that's why the issue can't be seen.

Comment: Please see `https://github.com/NonTechGuy/opacity-tweenmax` if you swap between the branches and repeatedly refresh the index.html in your browser you will see that on the pranaymajee branch which is your code the stacking of the h5 elements exists. Then swap to the nontechguy branch and repeatedly refresh the index.html and you will see that the stacking of h5 elements does not exist.

Comment: have you checked the code on the repo link above for clarity?